# Interpolating correctly between points in R using ggplot2 and axis scaling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data I want to graph on a semi-log scale, however I get some artifacts when there is a large jump between points. On linear scale, a straight line is drawn between subsequent points, which is a fine approximation for visualization. However, the exact same thing is done when using the log scale (either by using scale_x_log10 or scale_x_continuous with a log transformation). A line between two points on the semi-log scale should show up curved. In other words, this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 1), y = c(0, 1))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + scale_x_log10(limits = c(10^-3, 10^0))
```

produces this:

[image]

when I would expect something more like this:

[image]

generated by this code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, 0.01), y = seq(0, 1, 0.01))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + scale_x_log10(limits = c(10^-3, 10^0))
```

It's clear what's happening, but I'm not sure what the best way to fix the interpolation is. In the actual data I'm plotting there are a few jumps at various points, which makes the plots very misleading when trying to compare two lines. (They're ROC curves in this instance.)

One thought is I can search the data for jumps and fill in some interpolated points myself, but I'm hoping for a cleaner way that doesn't involve me adding in a bunch of fake data points.

Comment: I think it depends on how you would like to do the interpolation. You can either do a linear interpolation on the original scale, or a linear interpolation on the log-scale, or a spline interpolation on the original scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a transformation of the coordinate system, not a transformation of the scales. The distinction is that scale transformations take place before any statistical transformations, and coordinate transformations take place afterward. In this case, the "statistical transformation" is "draw a straight line between the points". With a transformed scale, the line is straight in the transformed (log) space; with a transformed coordinate, it is straight in the original (linear) space and therefore curved in log space.

```
# don't include 0 in the data because log 0 is -Inf
DF <- data.frame(x = c(0.1, 1), y = c(0.1, 1))
ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_trans(x="log10")
```

[image: ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0.1, 1), y = c(0.1, 1)), aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + coord_trans(x="log10")]

Comment: Awesome! Works exactly as I expected. I didn't realize there would be two separate transformations. Is there any time you really want to change just the scales rather than a coordinate transform? It seems like it'll always give you misleading graphs.

Comment: @Anthony You would specifically want a scale transformation when you want to work in the transformed space; think of a log-log plot where the straight line is in the transformed coordinates. Additionally, scale transformations can be used to bring other ordered, continuous data types (dates, times, etc.) into a numeric representation which can be plotted and manipulated.